# How to control hibernate reverse engineering @JoinTable and it's elements?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, reverse-engineering

I am using hibernate Reverse Engineering tool to generate pojo's from my database. Say I have two table's A and B in my database and another table ABMap which has two columns A_id and B_id that are foreign keys to table A and B respectively, and the primary key of ABMap is the composite key of A_id and B_id.
Now, when I build my project and generate the pojos, instead of ABMap being generated as a separate entity by hibernate, it is added into the entity A as a Set. Below is the snippet of code generated in entity A,

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = “ABMap”, schema= “myDB”, joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = “A_id”, nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
      @JoinColumn(name = “B_id”, nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set getBs() {
    return this.bs;
}

public void setBs(Set bs) {
    this.bs = bs;
}
```

Now the issue here is, using hibernate or Jpa I can do a insert into the ABMap table without actually having an entity of ABMap but I cannot update the same record since the updatable element in @JoinColumn is set to false by hibernate reverse engineering tool. Below is the sql error that occurs when an attempt is made to update the value of B_id.

> 2014-12-17 13:26:50,639 ERROR (qtp850520326-20) [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_A_B". The conflict occurred in database "myDB", table "B", column 'B_id'.

How can I set the updatable element in @JoinColumn to true?